# Adding json to java project

Tags: java, json, selenium

I have a problem with adding JSON file to my java project. Here's part of the code where I initialize it. I would appreciate if someone could tell me, where I made the mistake and how to do it.

```
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();            
JSONObject json = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(jsonData);
System.out.println(json.get("users/user/desktop/settingspanel.json"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@kjeraska

I guess what you are trying to parse json file in your Java project.

```
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();        
Object jsonData = jsonParser.parse(new FileReader("users/user/desktop/settingspanel.json"));
JSONObject json = (JSONObject) jsonData;
System.out.println(json.get("keyInYourJsonFile"));
```

For example: In your settingspanel.json file data:

```
 {
  "key1":"value2",
  "key2":"value2",
}
```

Hope this helps :).

Comment: Yes, that's what I tried to do. Thanks for the help! :)